# Iphone - Ghost Memory Leak

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks

I have absolutely no idea where this memory leak is from.  None of the links on the right trace it to a part of my code.  Does anyone know what causes this or how I can go about tracking it down?

*It happens moments after my code loads

[image]

Comment: What does your code do? Besides leak memory...

Comment: All kinds of stuff...  I think this comes from downloading and parsing an XML file using KissXML

https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to track down any issue is to litter your code with NSLog statements and breakpoints. Try to find which line is causing the problem, and then figure out how to fix it (thats the tricky bit). If you are using some other API, then it is posible that there is a leak in that, but probably pretty unlikely. More likely its your code leaking, so it should be possible to trace and find it eventually. Just a bit of a slow process.

Comment: I guess this is what ill do haha.  :)  Better than nothing I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't. You're looking at less than 1k of "leaked" memory (which may not actually be leaked; the leak detector isn't perfect). Cocoa itself has small leaks, and small things that appear to be leaks.

What you want to look for are leaks that are either large, or recur regularly. Chasing 1k of memory, even if it were you fault (which is possibly isn't), isn't worth the effort.

If you can create a small program that demonstrates the problem, it's worth opening a radar (bugreport.apple.com). It's good for Apple to make sure that they get rid of all of their small leaks (since they impact every program), and to fix Instruments to better filter out false positives. But for a single program it's not a good use of resources to chase every byte of memory.